# admin-ajax.php warning max input vars exceeded on layered pop plugins

Tags: plugins, php, ajax, htaccess

Everytime i try to save my modifications on the Layared pop-ups plugin i have a "Service is not available" message and my modifications are not saved.
When i look into the element inspector i have this:
`"Warning: Unknown: Input variables exceeded 1000. To in crease the limit       change max_input_vars in php.ini. in Unknown on line 0"`
I tried increasing this limit by adding this in the .htaccess file:

    `php_value max_input_vars 4000`
But it doesn't work. Also, i don't have access to the php.ini file of my server because it's a mutualized server. I tried editing a php.ini file at the root of my wordpress site, and indicating the right path to it in my .htaccess but no good results.

Comment: this is a security setting. You should put the time to first understand why it is like that before attempting changing it. As for why it does not work, you should contact your hosting, they probably to not let you change it from the htaccess. In general, sending many varibles is just wrong, look for a better plugin

Comment: @zac Sending 1000 input vars is already too much. If a plugin does that, it's terrible design wise. You better work on that instead of increasing `max_input_vars`. With too many input vars allowed, your site will be more vulnerable to DOS attack. Read more here: http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-vars

Comment: Thanks for your responses! The thing is i have this plugin installed on many other websites and i never experienced this problem on the same hosting provider. But i'll try something else then.

Comment: @Zac please contact your hosting provider through their support system. Perhaps there is another issue you don't know about.